# Magento module Custom Magento Reports blank page?

Tags: module, custom, reports

I try to install magento (in version 1.9.3.7) module from GitHub [Custom Magento reports using sql](https://github.com/kalenjordan/custom-reports). I have install module via modman from this guide (install via modman): [How to install module in Magento](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2014/11/how-to-install-a-magento-module).

After installation via modman, I get message, that custom_reports_sql is successfuly compiled, after flush Magento Storage in menu section Reports apears menu "Special Reports" and inside this menu it appears menus e.g.: Special: New Customers ... But clicking in any of this reports I get **blank page**.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After debuging I find that modman did not copy all files from github to directory /www/html/magento/app *